# Order mysql fields from several tables

Tags: mysql

I need to achieve the following and having an issue in doing so.
Here's the situation:

```
product
-----------------------------
id  sku     is_top  name
-----------------------------
1   aaa     1       Item 1   
2   bbb     0       Item 2
3   ccc     1       Item 3
4   ddd     1       Item 4
5   eee     1       Item 5

product_price
-----------------------------
product_id  price   type
-----------------------------
1           1.23    regular
1           1.01    special
2           3.34    regular
3           3.45    regular
4           2.67    regular
5           5.55    regular

product_wholesale_price
-----------------------------
product_id  price   minimum_count
-----------------------------
1           1.12    10
1           0.95    25
2           2.12    40
3           3.00    40
5           4.00    30

product_special_price
-----------------------------
product_id  price   customer_id
-----------------------------
1           1.00    7
2           2.00    20
3           2.50    45
```

Ordering needs to be like this:

1. Products with is_top = 1 and has a record in product_price with
   type = 'special'
2. Products with is_top = 1 and no special price
   record
3. All other products
4. Also ordered by price in descending
   order, using the highest price available for a product. For example,
   product with id = 1 has the following prices: 1.23, 1.01, 1.12,
   1.00. We need to order using the highest, which in this case is 1.23.

So the desirable result order would be this:

1. Item 1 with price 1.23 (is top and has special price)
2. Item 5 wit price 5.55 (is top)
3. Item 3 with price 3.45 (is top)
4. Item 4 with price 2.67 (is top)
5. Item 2 with price 3.34 (no top, no special price)

Is something like that even possible in a single query?

Comment: Please follow this while asking a question -
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query @Deez

Comment: Yes you can nest queries, if you give a better description of what you want

Comment: Too many criteria for my feeble brain.  Can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ORDER BY (is_top = 1 AND type = 'special') DESC, is_top DESC, price DESC
```

When a condition is true, the value is `1`, otherwise `0`, so using a condition expression as a `DESC` ordering criteria puts the rows that match the criteria first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, MAX(pp.price) FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_price pp
ON p.id=pp.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_special_price psp
ON p.id=psp.product_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
ORDER BY MAX(p.is_top AND pp.type='special') DESC,
    MAX(p.is_top AND psp.price IS NULL) DESC, 
    MAX(pp.price) DESC;
```

Also if you want greatest price from several different columns, in select (and also in ORDER BY) instead of `MAX(pp.price)` you can write something like `GREATEST(MAX(pp.price), MAX(COALESCE(psp.price,0)))`.